# android streaming radio app doesn't works

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I've done a streaming radio app for android.

If I set as datasource an mp3 the app works :

```
mp.setDataSource("http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3")
```

Instead if I set this radio stream URL doesn't works:

```
mp.setDataSource("http://62.149.220.142:8000/listen.pls");
```

or

```
mp.setDataSource("http://62.149.220.142:8000/");
```

Why?

This is a part of code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Buffering.....");
        pd.show();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
    //mp.setDataSource("http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3");
    //mp.setDataSource("http://62.149.220.142:8000/listen.pls");
    //mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse("http://62.149.220.142:8000/listen.pls"));

    //sito
    mp.setDataSource("108.163.197.146:8002/");


    mp.prepareAsync();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("StreamAudioDemo", e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Stefano

Comment: plz try this mp.setDataSource("http://108.163.197.146:8002/"); and let me know status , 1st is .pls you need to fetch url from .pls – Rstar 7 mins ago

Comment: with your dataSource doesn't works. In LogCat appears the error (1, -2147483648) with tag MediaPlayer. The Activity goes in the completed state.

Comment: will you put some code so i can identify problem ?

Comment: I've past code in the main post upper.

Comment: have you set as `mp.setDataSource("http://108.163.197.146:8002/");`

Comment: I tried also with http: now the error in logcat there isn't but the activity goes in completed state. I'm behind a proxy (i've configured eclipse). In the Logcat, the last entry is: 1)connect to 108.163.197.146:8002/ @0    2) mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -111

Comment: I replace mp.prepareAsync() with mp.prepare() to see errors. In the logcat now appears error (1, -111)

Comment: Finally I tried this mp.setDataSource("http://pub3.rockradio.com:80/rr_numetal");

Comment: It's Works!!! But I must use http://62.149.220.142:8000/

Comment: I must use 62.149.220.142:8000 but doesn't works! I paste this URL in Itunes and works...I don't know what is the problem :(

Comment: Perhaps I find the problem : proxy... For this site I've the access blocked: http://www.shoutcast.com/Internet-Radio/MaGmA%20Global%20Radio... I install app on a smartphone..Later I tell u the result..

Comment: With a phone connected to wifi radio "pub3.rockradio.com:80/rr_numetal" works.

Comment: With a phone connected to wifi radio "http://108.163.197.146:8002/" and "http://62.149.220.142:8000" don't work. I don't know the reason. :(

Comment: i will test this urls here and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Hello I try this and it's work for me :

Step1 : I created the file network_security_config.xml under xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Step2 : and I added in manifest in app tag :

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Step3 Now the java class

```
public class AudioPlayer {

    MediaPlayer player;

    public void playAudio() {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            player.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                    .build());
        } else {
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        try {
            player.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                mp.start();

            });
            player.setDataSource("http://199.180.75.118/stream");
            player.prepareAsync();


        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("AudioPlayer",e.getMessage());
        }
        // below line is use to display a toast message.
    }
}
```